# How to Bind/change the below HTML button drop down lists using Angular Reactive forms

Tags: html, angular, angular-reactive-forms

```
        <div class="c-field">
          <label [attr.for]="dropdownId"
              class="c-field__label">{{label}}</label>
             <div class="c-dropdown" [attr.id]="dropdownId"
                aria-labelledby="dropdown-demo-no-error-dropdown-label"
               aria-describedby="dropdown-demo-no-error-field-helper">
           <button class="c-btn c-dropdown__toggle c-btn--dropdown"
                type="button" [(ngModel)]="selectedValue"
                data-toggle="dropdown" (click)="onDropdownValueChange($event)"
                aria-haspopup="true"
                aria-expanded="false"
                aria-describedby="dropdown-demo-no-error-button"
                [attr.id]="dropdownId">
          <span class="c-dropdown__text">Dropdown</span>
        </button>
             <div class="c-dropdown__menu dropdown-menu"
             aria-labelledby="dropdown-demo-no-error"
             x-placement="bottom-start"
             style="position: absolute; will-change: transform; top: 0px; left: 
         0px; transform: translate3d(0px, 40px, 0px);">
          <hr>
          <button class="c-dropdown__item " *ngFor="let item of dataSource"
                  type="button"
                  [attr.id]="dropdownId + item.id">{{item.text}}</button>      
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="isFormSubmitted && dropdownFormControl.errors">      
          <span class="c-field__error" id="dropdown-demo-error-field-error">
          {{ label }} {{ errorMessages.RequiredField }}</span>
        </div>
        <span class="c-field__helper" *ngIf="helperText"
              id="dropdown-demo-no-error-field-helper">{{helperText}}</span>
      </div>
         </div>
```

Here the above HTML for drop down the binding. but when 
    I click on button click event drop-down event is not firing. 
    Could you please suggested me how to change event will work?

Comment: Your example uses Template-driven Forms not Reactive Forms. Did you mean you want to convert it to Reactive Forms or did you just want to know why the code is not working as is?

Answer (score 0):

You can't bind using Angular Reactive Form as this is a html button and both Reactive Forms (via FormControlDirective directive) or by Template-driven Forms (via the ngModel directive) wont work. Both of these directives are designed to work with html input elements.

I don't think it would make much sense if they were html input elements of type button either. Since in that case the value attribute would determine the text on the button and would not change via user interactions.

I think your best bet is to handle the updating of the `selectedValue` value through click events on the 'drop down' list itself:

```
 <div class="c-dropdown__menu dropdown-menu"
             aria-labelledby="dropdown-demo-no-error"
             x-placement="bottom-start"
             style="position: absolute; will-change: transform; top: 0px; left: 
         0px; transform: translate3d(0px, 40px, 0px);">
          <hr>
          <button class="c-dropdown__item " *ngFor="let item of dataSource"
                  type="button"
                  [attr.id]="dropdownId + item.id" (click)="onDropdownValueChange(item)">{{item.text}}</button>      
        </div>
```